# Google search results in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-search

To the extend of my research, Google stopped allowing its page being displayed in an iframe. There used to be a URL (http://gog.is) which showed Google results and allowed display in an iframe. That site went down recently.

I'm wondering is there any way at all now to have Google search results in an iframe? What's the best solution/alternative to have search results in an iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Well google does not want t be framed so only way around it is a proxy that removes the headers

Comment: @epascarello Ok we can do that but the issue is also with the result links. They point to google first then redirect to the resulting website. If that redirection happens partially through the browser (iframe) it would fail. Do you have any idea whether the results would be displayed normally when clicked?

Comment: Reason you are not using their custom search or their apis?

Comment: @epascarello tell me more about that

Comment: @epascarello Note that I want to search the entire web for something, and not custom search within my app/website

Answer (score 7):

You can use this link instead of https://google.com/ , it works pretty good:

> https://www.google.com/search?igu=1

With specific word you can use this link:

> https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q=YOUR+WORD

Than iframe should looks as this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"></iframe>
```